# After changing name of a file it goes parent directory

Tags: php, filenames, glob, txt

I'm writing a PHP code that takes names from input.txt file and with those names it changes the names of files in the image folder.

My code is:

```
<?php
$array = explode(".png", file_get_contents('input.txt'));

$directory='C:\wamp64\www\Replace image names with input\images';
$extension = '.png';
$a=0;
$newName='';

$dir = "images/*";

foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
{
    if(!is_dir($file)) {
        echo basename($file)."\n";
        $newName=$array[$a].".png";
        rename($file, $newName);
        $a++;
    }
}    
?>
```

It works but at last, files in the 'image' folder go `C:\wamp64\www\Replace image names with input directory`. (Parent directory)

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in the end goes..."? Are you saying it saves all the images into the parent folder? Or something else? Please clarify, and maybe give an example.

Comment: Seems, you set a  relative path for a destination file. So, it is moved to the dir from which  the script runs. Set the full path

Comment: yes @ADyson, They go to parent folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more clear. Here is what your code is doing:

```
$dir = "images/*";

foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
// at this point $file === "images/filename"
    if(!is_dir($file)) {
        echo basename($file)."\n";
        $newName=$array[$a].".png";
// You set the $newName to newname.png
        rename($file, $newName);
// you replace "images/filename" with "newname.png"
        $a++;
    }
}
```

effectively you've written a move and rename function. For simplicity you can just do:

```
$newName="images/".$array[$a].".png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on splash58's comment:

Use `scandir($directory)` instead of `glob($dir)`

Answer (score 1):

I understand your worry perfectly. I tried your code with the rename function and got the same problem. The solution is to provide the absolute path of the directory containing the images you want to rename and replace as second argument. Do this:
...
rename($file, "images/" . $newname);
...

This worked for me - renamed and replaced all old files with new named files.